# FireStore Inside a Android Service Not Working. Database Locked ERROR

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I got the following Error when I tried to access data from firestore. Tried setting persistence to true yet getting the same error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeyi.run(Unknown Source)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                          
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to gain exclusive lock to the Firestore client's offline persistence. This generally means you are using 
Firestore from multiple processes in your app. Keep in mind that multi- 
process Android apps execute the code in your Application class in all 
processes, so you may need to avoid initializing Firestore in your 
Application class. If you are intentionally using Firestore from multiple 
processes, you can only enable offline persistence (i.e. call s 
setPersistenceEnabled(true)) in one of them.

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetz.zza(Unknown Source)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeqp.zza(Unknown Source)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeqr.run(Unknown Source)
```

My App has a Service in it and running in a seperate process

```
 <service
        android:name=".ReceivingOrderService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":receivingorder"></service>
```

Comment: Could you give specific code as to how you're using FireStore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Guys I just played with code and set the

```
setPersistenceEnabled(true)
```

to

```
setPersistenceEnabled(false)
```